# Java Google Docs API - Document Conversion Tool used in a standalone java program

Tags: java, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, file-conversion

First time asking something, let's see if I don't mess up.

My question is, I believe, a simple one:

- Can one you use the Document Conversion Tool present in the Google Docs API to convert a PPTX/PPT to ODP (OpenDocument Presentation) without any intent of uploading it to Google Docs.

Basically I just want to use the conversion tool and have the file to save. Is it possible?

Thank a bunch for your time.
Your contribution will keep the entire World spinning.. well, at least my World :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use the API to convert file into different formats if they are not uploaded to Google Drive.

You can always upload a file to Drive, convert it to a different format and then delete the original file, but I don't why you might want to do that :)

Comment: To Convert Documents, more specifically Presentation Documents into the ODP Format and I cant find one anywhere so I asked if this solution was possible. And thank you for your answer but I will be working in a no-internet-zone!